# Google Cloud search resources in organizations

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google cloud platform and still learning. I am interested in organizations, where I will have multiple accounts in multiple regions. Is there a way I can query resources based on some configuration parameters across all my accounts? Example - list all Virtual machines which are in US West region, micro size and currently stopped.

Comment: Do you mean inside a particular product (micro size VMs - possibly compute engine/GCE?) or across all GCP products?

Comment: Your example could be done through `gcloud SDK`: `gcloud compute instances list --filter="machineType:f1-micro AND status:terminated AND zone:us-west" --project <your-project-id>`

Answer (score 1):

"Multiple accounts in multiple regions" is an AWS idea which is really antithetical to how things are done in Google Cloud. GCP gives you a lot of tools to slice-and-dice your systems, but none of them work in the "multiple accounts/multiple regions" paradigm.

But if you insist on going that route, your best bet may be to create custom bash scripts which harness `gcloud`, the CLI for GCP. It is a pleasure to use, and could probably do any sort of automation, even across accounts, that you have in mind.